# Extract from XML in PHP

Tags: php, xml

```
<toplevel>
 <CompleteSuggestion>
  <suggestion data="shook ones part 2"/>
 </CompleteSuggestion>
 <CompleteSuggestion>
  <suggestion data="shook me all night long"/>
 </CompleteSuggestion>
 <CompleteSuggestion>
  <suggestion data="shook ones instrumental"/>
 </CompleteSuggestion>
 <CompleteSuggestion>
  <suggestion data="shook me all night long lyrics"/>
 </CompleteSuggestion>
</toplevel>
```

I want to extract "shook ones part 2" from this XML output. I have gone through every solution, but I'm unable to do this.
I tried this:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar&hl=en&q=shook&ds=yt';
$exact = simplexml_load_file($url);
echo $exact->CompleteSuggestion[0]->suggestion;
?>
```

Comment: maybe you can post one of your attempts

Comment: edited with what i tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`shook ones part 2` is value of an attribute `data` of `suggestion`.
So you should get all attributes of a `suggestion` with function `attributes()` and select `data`:

```
$exact = simplexml_load_file('$url');
echo $exact->CompleteSuggestion[0]->suggestion->attributes()->data;
```

Answer (score 0):

Omit the single quotes in

```
simplexml_load_file('$url');
                    ^    ^
```

Comment: oh yeah, i just forgot that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DOMDocumen](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)t for this. The below example will search the tag suggestion and echo the data attribute:

```
$domDocument = new DOMDocument();
$domDocument->loadXML( $xml );

$value = $domDocument->getElementsByTagName( "suggestion" );
foreach ( $value as $e ) {
    echo $e->getAttribute( "data" )."<br>";
}
```